# Problem with creating proper linear regression model for my experiment

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model

I am working with microarray data and I am trying to find differentially expressed genes affected by gut microbiota in mice. I have 6 subjects, out of which I got 4 different samples one from L-negative cells and one from L-positive cells from both colonic and ileal tissues. In the following you can see the designed matrix for each microarray file:

> ```
> file    subject   gutMic    tissue    Lcells
> --------------------------------------------
> IPCR1       1     CR        ileum     Lpos
> CPCR1       1     CR        colon     Lpos
> INCR1       1     CR        ileum     Lneg
> CNCR1       1     CR        colon     Lneg
> IPCR2       2     CR        ileum     Lpos
> CPCR2       2     CR        colon     Lpos
> INCR2       2     CR        ileum     Lneg
> CNCR2       2     CR        colon     Lneg
> IPCR3       3     CR        ileum     Lpos
> CPCR3       3     CR        colon     Lpos
> INCR3       3     CR        ileum     Lneg
> CNCR3       3     CR        colon     Lneg
> IPGF1       4     GF        ileum     Lpos
> CPGF1       4     GF        colon     Lpos
> INGF1       4     GF        ileum     Lneg
> CNGF1       4     GF        colon     Lneg
> IPGF2       5     GF        ileum     Lpos
> CPGF2       5     GF        colon     Lpos
> INGF2       5     GF        ileum     Lneg
> CNGF2       5     GF        colon     Lneg
> IPGF3       6     GF        ileum     Lpos
> CPGF3       6     GF        colon     Lpos
> INGF3       6     GF        ileum     Lneg
> CNGF3       6     GF        colon     Lneg
> ```

Now I would like to analyse the effect of gut microbiota in L-negative comparing to L-positive cells regardless of tissue type (i.e. GF ~ CR in Lneg and compare it with GF ~ CR in Lpos). I know for data coming from same subject I should consider correlation raising from measurement in the same subject to reduce biased result. But, here I don't know how I can reduce effect of samples coming from different tissues of one subject?!! As an example files INGF3 and CNGF3 are coming from same subject but different tissues and I would like to sum them up as consider them replicates of one sample.